# How to get the sum of values in a list within a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum

This a simplified question for an assignment I am struggling with. The goal is to get the sum of the numbers in the 'Paid' list within the dictionary. I am receiving a type error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

This is my current code:

```
dict1 = {"JS" : {"Paid" : [200, 400, 500, 600]}}
total = sum(d['Paid'] for d in dict1)
print(total)
```

Answer (score 2):

`for d in dict1:` just iterates over keys in dictionary `dict1`. To get sum of the list you can use next example:

```py
dict1 = {"JS": {"Paid": [200, 400, 500, 600]}}
total = sum(v for d in dict1.values() for v in d["Paid"])
print(total)
```

Prints:

```
1700
```

Comment: Do you need to loop over the values or just pass the list to sum()?

Comment: @CaptainCaveman Calling `sum(d["Paid"] for d in dict1.values())` results in `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'`. `sum()` doesn't know how to add `0` + `list`.

Comment: I was referring to how I implemented it.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman If OP wants only the sum of `["JS"]["Paid"]`. then yes. It's enough :) +1

Comment: Ah, ok, so your solution would address a dictionary with more key, value pairs. Cool, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
dict1 = {"JS" : {"Paid" : [200, 400, 500, 600]}}

total = sum(dict1["JS"]["Paid"])

# output: 1700
print(total)
```